SwiftUI textfields reset on app backgrounded
I have a tab-based SwiftUI app that uses .sheet() to present a View that contains email and passwords fields. If I type into those fields then background and foreground the app, the fields are cleared, which makes it impossible to use a password manager. If instead, the view is inlined within the .sheet()'s content, the fields are not cleared.
Unexpectedly, removing either the TabView or NavigationStack results in the fields not being cleared. It seems that TabView and NavigationStack trigger .sheet()'s content to be recreated such that the view's state is lost.
What's going on here and what's the right way to achieve the desired result?
Repro steps:

tap "Form 1"
type something into the email and password fields
background the app
foreground the app

Expect: field values are retained
Actual: field values are reset
Tapping "Form 2", where the view's contents are inlined, works as expected.
Demo app:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingForm1 = false
    @State var isShowingForm2 = false
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    Button("Form 1") {
                        isShowingForm1 = true
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingForm1) {
                        FormView()
                            .padding()
                    }

                    Button("Form 2") {
                        isShowingForm2 = true
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingForm2) {
                        VStack {
                            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab1", systemImage: "circle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FormView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
        }
    }
}


Try this approach, move the .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingForm1){...} outside the
TabView, and use @State private var ....

Thanks for the suggestion.
That worked, but in a real app, it seems impractical to move .sheet() to TabView.
Based on your suggestion, I tried moving .sheet() to List, and that worked, which is a workable approach in my app.

I don't understand the discrepancy in the two .sheet()s in the demo app.

There is no reason (or impracticality) why the sheet needs to be inside the TabView. I can only answer the question you asked, with the code you provided. I cannot guess what your real App is doing. Nevertheless, if you found a working solution based on my answer, consider accepting it.
